# Create a select list from other form entries?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a form page that has several text fields the user inputs. Is it possible to make one field a select list that is populated with only entries that the user inputs elsewhere?

Comment: Probably; what are exactly "entries that user inputs elsewhere"?

Comment: Sure, as along as those inputs make it to session state, and you refresh the relevant item.

Comment: Hi Gregory, did you still need help with this?

Comment: Yes I do still need help.